# How to show an whole list in pdf page using iTextpdf?

Tags: android, arraylist, itext, android-sqlite

I have two tables in database. By uniting both I get a new table. Now I want to show this table's values in a pdf page but its showing only a single row. How can I show the whole tables values in the PdfTable. I am using iText Library here. Database method is here :

```
public List<PSummaryModel> testMethodSummary(){
    String ps = "Not Found";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "select p_name, sum(i_amount) i_amount, sum(e_amount) e_amount, sum(i_amount)-sum(e_amount) profit " +
            "from (" +
            "select sr, date, project_id, expense_id expense_id, 0 i_amount, e_amount e_amount, description " +
            "from expense_voucher" +
            " union all " +
            "select sr, date, project_id, income_id income_id, i_amount i_amount, 0 e_amount, description " +
            "from income_voucher) v, projects p " +
            "where v.project_id=p.p_id " +
            "group by p_name ";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    List<PSummaryModel> summaryModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        PSummaryModel pSummaryModel = new PSummaryModel(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getLong(1), cursor.getLong(2), cursor.getLong(3));
        summaryModelList.add(pSummaryModel);
    }
    return summaryModelList;
}
```

here is the pdf table code:

```
listOfSummaryModel = databaseHelper.testMethodSummary();
            for (PSummaryModel pSummaryModel : listOfSummaryModel) {

                PdfPCell cell = null;
                cell = new PdfPCell(Phrase.getInstance(pSummaryModel.getP_title()));
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                tables.addCell(cell);

                cell = new PdfPCell(Phrase.getInstance(String.valueOf(pSummaryModel.getTotalIncome())));
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                tables.addCell(cell);

                cell = new PdfPCell(Phrase.getInstance(String.valueOf(pSummaryModel.getTotalExpense())));
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                tables.addCell(cell);

                cell = new PdfPCell(Phrase.getInstance(String.valueOf(pSummaryModel.getProfit())));
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                tables.addCell(cell);

                document.add(tables);
                document.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the table and close the document inside the `for` loop at its end. I.e. you do that after adding the first row only.

To fix this move those instructions outside the loop, i.e. change this

```
for (PSummaryModel pSummaryModel : listOfSummaryModel) {

    PdfPCell cell = null;
    cell = new PdfPCell(Phrase.getInstance(pSummaryModel.getP_title()));
    ...
    tables.addCell(cell);

    document.add(tables);
    document.close();
}
```

to this:

```
for (PSummaryModel pSummaryModel : listOfSummaryModel) {

    PdfPCell cell = null;
    cell = new PdfPCell(Phrase.getInstance(pSummaryModel.getP_title()));
    ...
    tables.addCell(cell);
}

document.add(tables);
document.close();
```